# Krull dimension question - Show that it has a unique primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, integral-extensions

**PROBLEM:** Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain that is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $J$ be a non-zero ideal of $A$. Show that if $I=J\cap \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has height 2, then $J$ has a single primary decomposition.

**Attempt:** Since $A$ is an integer extent of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, I got
$$\dim (A) = \dim (\mathbb{Z}[x]) = 2 = ht(I).$$
I think the biggest problem is not knowing for sure what I have to prove to ensure that $J$ admits of a single primary decomposition. At first I tried to prove that all components of the decomposition were single primes. I don't know if that fixes it. If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you take $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $I=J=(2,x^2)$. Then $J$ itself is primary but $J=(2,x^2)\cap (2,x)$ is also a primary decomposition.